# If a fluorescent atom absorbs UV and emits visible light, then how is energy conserved?

Tags: photons, energy-conservation, atomic-physics, fluorescence

Light has a lower frequency than UV, so unless energy is also released in other forms, how can energy be conserved? What other forms is energy released as for fluorescence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually IR.  There are different ways this could happen, but a simple model is just to see that the absorption and transmission processes don't have to be identical.

The UV photon could take a molecule from the ground state to some level "5".  Then the molecule could relax from "5" to "3", transmitting an IR photon, and then again from "3" to ground, transmitting a visible photon.

Or since most materials are in thermal equilibrium with their surroundings, the remaining energy could just be lost in the noise of IR and thermal exchange rather than be tracked as coming directly from a particular received photon.